# Concatenate vs Sum MS Access 2013 textboxes in form - hh:nn:ss+hh:nn:ss

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to simply sum together two textboxes via the Form_Timer(). I am able to subtract,

```
txtmyqueusedtime = Now()

 txtmyqueduration = Format([txtmyqueusedtime] - [txtmyquestarttime], "hh:nn:ss")
```

but when I attempt to add it comes back concatenated.

```
txtmyquecmbtimer = [txtmyqueduration] + [txtmyquecmbquedur]
```

EX: if I need 00:00:03 + 00:00:01 added I need to return 00:00:04. Instead I am returning 00:00:0300:00:01

Details:

I have tried many different ways to get it to sum properly, unfortunately I've been met with a Type Mismatch error each time. [txtmyquecmbtimer] should be adding a persons queued time (static) with current duration of the form being opened [txtmyqueduration].

Thanks for any help -- Happy to supply additional details if needed.

UPDATE -- Figured this one out finally

```
*Private Sub Form_Timer()
Dim combtime As Date
Dim duration As Date
Dim sumtime As Date
   txtmyqueusedtime = Now()
   txtmyqueduration = Format([txtmyqueusedtime] - [txtmyquestarttime], "hh:nn:ss")
        If IsNull(DLookup("CombinedDuration", "Agent_Queue", "SysAcct = '" & txtmyquesysacct & "'")) Then
        Me.txtmyquecmbtimer.Value = [txtmyqueduration]
        Else

        combtime = CDate(DLookup("CombinedDuration", "Agent_Queue", "SysAcct = '" & txtmyquesysacct & "'"))
        duration = CDate(txtmyqueduration)
        sumtime = duration + combtime
        Me.txtmyquecmbtimer.Value = sumtime
End If
End Sub*
```

Comment: You may need to convert the values to a date/time format before adding them together. Try `TIMESERIAL()` or `CDate()`

Comment: CDate() worked beautifully -- thank you!

Comment: Use `DATEDIFF()` to subtract datetimes, and `DATADD()` to add to an interval to a date

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateDiff()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) to subtract datetimes, and [DateAdd()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php) to add to an interval to a date

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Dim combtime As Date
    Dim duration As Long
    Dim sumtime As Date
    txtmyqueusedtime = Now()
    txtmyqueduration = DateDiff("S", [txtmyqueusedtime], [txtmyquestarttime])
    If IsNull(DLookup("CombinedDuration", "Agent_Queue", "SysAcct = '" & txtmyquesysacct & "'")) Then
        Me.txtmyquecmbtimer.Value = [txtmyqueduration]
    Else    
        combtime = CDate(DLookup("CombinedDuration", "Agent_Queue", "SysAcct = '" & txtmyquesysacct & "'"))
        duration = Clng(txtmyqueduration)
        sumtime = DateAdd ("S", duration, combtime)
        Me.txtmyquecmbtimer.Value = sumtime
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: `duration` is a nuber of seconds, not a Time value.